# how to get row with filter and index column in python dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a text file, test.csv, with a given content:

```
date        price   curr    score           
2020-03-08  87.925  72.94   1
2020-03-15  73.460  42.48   1
2020-03-22  317.12  139.21  -1
2020-03-29  28.19   13.76   1
```

I am taking a date as parameter and it is given as a string with format of "2020-03-15", and I am trying to get a row associated with a given date if the score value is -1:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df_result=pd.read_csv("./test.csv", index_col="date", sep="\t", parse_dates=True)
df_result.loc[df_result['anomaly']==-1][datetime.strptime('2020-03-08', '%Y-%m-%d').date()]
```

It gives an error and I am not able to get the row associated with date '2020-03-08'. Please also consider that I need to set the date column as an index.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df_result.loc[(df_result['anomaly']==-1)&(df['date']=='2020-03-08')]
```